# jquery code sometimes work sometimes no

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I've a jquery code confusing me! Sometimes it works fine and sometimes no!
although i had same problem with css! i thought because web browser. still the same problem

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
$('.glyphicon-chevron-up').click(function() {
    var vote = "up";
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    var userid = $('#this').val();
    $.post('data.php', {cmtid: value, op: vote, user: userid}, function(data){
        if(data == "-1") {
            alert('Something went wrong');
        }
        else if(data == "-4") {
            alert('You already voted');
        }
        else if(data == "-2") {
            alert('You cant vote up again');
        }
        else if(data == "-3") {
            alert('You cant vote down again');
        }
        else {
            var vdata = '#vdata' + value;
            $(vdata).html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" id="voteup" value="<?php echo $comment->data()->id; ?>"></i>
</div>
```

is there anything wrong code?!
it seems simple

Comment: some times what is not working?

Comment: i dont understand why you have this `$('#this').val();` since you don't have an html element with an id of `this`... atleast from your codes given us.

Comment: Do you have another script above this script ?

Comment: Craftein i do have but it's hidden and not in the current part of php code,

ArunPJohny this code! works but sometimes crash

Nucleo1985 No

Comment: Perhaps this `not working` refers to frequent changes on .js files that are cached on old versions ?

Comment: What part of *this code* is not working?

Comment: @vlzvl but i've tried it on many different browsers and laptops.

Comment: @blurd that's the question. even i've tried to make an ALERT without any codes! still nothing appears

Comment: Since we are on guessing phase, what's on the console? perhaps there is a javascript error previously not allowing anything else to be executed.

Comment: is there a chance that the element `glyphicon-chevron-up` is created dynamically? also add an error handler to check whether the ajax request is failing some time

Comment: If you're not seeing any of the alerts, it might mean the call is failing. `$.post()` specifies a success handler, but not an error handler.

Comment: @blurd Yeah what's about an alert before $.post() it should appear?

Comment: @user2751638 can you check the browser developer tool's network tab to see whether the ajax request is going and what is its response status.... also add an alert as the first line in the click handler to see whether the click handler is called every time

Comment: "work sometimes no" is NOT a reasonable description of the problem.  Explain exactly what happens.  Explain what you see in the debug console.  Explain what happens when you put a breakpoint or `console.log(data)` in the success handler.  Explain what happens when you specify an error handler for the `.post()`.  Reasonable debugging AND an explanation of the problem is required here.  This question should probably be closed because you haven't made a decent description of the problem, described what you've done to look into the problem or tried basic debugging/problem solving steps.

Comment: For those interested, the problem was the `click` event wasn't triggering.  :|

Comment: Can you guys please vote up for blurd! without him i really wouldn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without clarification, it's hard to tell what your problem is.  Hopefully, this will help you.  Open your browser's console before you run the script (<kbd>f12</kbd>) so it will break at the `debugger;` statements and you can see the console.

*If you never see "The button was clicked." in the console, your problem is probably with your selector.*

[This article](http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188084/jQuery-and-Ajax-Error-Detection-and-Handling) may help you pick up some tips on how to debug these types of problems.  Chrome has a built in developer console that is, in my opinion, *way* better than Firebug, but the idea is the same.

Good luck.

```
$(function () {
    console.log('The DOM is ready.');

    if ($('.glyphicon-chevron-up').length === 0) {
      console.warn('Nothing matches this selector.');
    }

    $('.glyphicon-chevron-up').click(function () {
        console.log('The button was clicked.');

        var vote = "up";
        var value = $(this).attr('value');
        var userid = $('#this').val();

        // hit F8 to continue to see if the ajax call works
        console.log('about to send', {cmtid: value, op: vote, user: userid});
        debugger;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'data.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {cmtid: value, op: vote, user: userid},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('here is the response', data);
                debugger;

                if (data == "-1") {
                    alert('Something went wrong');
                } else if(data == "-4") {
                    alert('You already voted');
                } else if(data == "-2") {
                    alert('You cant vote up again');
                } else if(data == "-3") {
                    alert('You cant vote down again');
                } else {
                    var vdata = '#vdata' + value;
                    $(vdata).html(data);
                }
            },

            error: function () {
                console.error('the call failed');
                debugger;
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: i've tried it, thanks alot, but it seems that the buttons is not clicking.

Comment: If the problem is that clicking the button is not working, you should **really** update your question with that info.  A lot of people are willing to help.

Comment: I Found the problem =), First of all i'm so thankful to you trying to help me. i appreciate that.
The soultion was i did margin on the top div of the button tag with margin-left: -30px, so actually i need to click on that area! why this happend i don't know :D

Comment: @user2751638, good to hear.  Please feel free to give me an up-vote if this helped.

Comment: i wish i could i could but the guys killed me with the reputation down, i can't vote up!